# Handle notification messages in a backgrounded app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Currently, I'm using firebase push notification for notification. I have implemented the `onMessageReceived()` method using `FirebaseMessagingService`. When in foreground state, the `onMessageReceived()` method for notifications is triggered, but when the app is in the background state, `onMessageReceived()` is not called.

I'm not getting any type of data that I might have set on the server. I have done some R&D, but all the solutions show some `handleIntent()` for the specific library or some solution for using `getIntent()` and I'm using the Firebase library version above 17.3.4.

Could anyone show me the right way to use Firebase notification when the app is in 
background state and killed state?

Comment: Its easy. Your intent is sent to the main activity. Check if the intent is null or not and cycle through the keys.
`String your_value;
Object value;`
 `if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
                value = getIntent().getExtras().get(key);

                if(key.equals("your_key")){
                    your_value = String.valueOf(value)

}`

Comment: @Pemba  I'll send an intent to main Activity but in the background state its not load data.  I'll check both the state data is loaded when the app is foreground state. Not any single key found which I'll set on the server.

Comment: so you want to load data when the notification arrives??

Comment: @Pemba yes  I want notification data on my starting activity

Comment: So you want to tap on the notification then open the app then process your data right? This will work.

Comment: @Pemba I'll do the same thing but the app is open but data is not loaded. Because of no data to getIntent.

Comment: wait I'll post a proper answer below

Comment: @Pemba Single In foreground state i got the data otherwise not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the apps foreground state the `onMessageReceived` is called but in the background state it will not be called. Therefore in your main activity put loop through the extras in the intent.

```
 Object value;
        String str;
        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
                value = getIntent().getExtras().get(key);

                if(key.equals("key")){
                    str = String.valueOf(value);

                }
            }

        }
```

The "key" is the one you sent from your console.
[image]

In my case the `str` will be equal to "test notification"

Comment: okay, I'll do the same thing but in the case of server-side language send me a push notification on my app. And I'm not getting any value  in the background state

Comment: This is way to do it.
read the accepted answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358462/firebase-onmessagereceived-not-called-when-app-in-background

Comment: and if you can help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53393180/get-real-time-internet-speed-in-android/53516094?noredirect=1#comment93902905_53516094

Comment: I'll Try all the conditions as well as both end but I'm not getting any data on server-side on background side.but in firebase console I'll send notification and  I'll get data. please let me know how to do. If someone here done it, please share your code.

Comment: The code is up there.. that's how you do it. Keep trying

Comment: let me know one thing I've to receive a notification with data message in the background and when I'll use get intent() than not get the data. Any other method for receiving notification data.?

Comment: let me know one thing for in the background side any service to handle the notification.?

Comment: no there is not.
If you take time and read the answer in the link by @János

This is working as intended, notification messages are delivered to your onMessageReceived callback only when your app is in the foreground. If your app is in the background or closed then a notification message is shown in the notification center, and **any data from that message is passed to the intent** . So thats it. All data is passed on the intent of the activity launched by it.

Comment: see the link and read it again,use my code and accept and upvote my answer before this question is closed off as a duplicate. I needs reps for setting up a new bounty.